# Generate maven jar like the eclipse jar

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, maven, jar

since I'm having trouble with jars for weeks, hopefully someone may help me here!

My project is written in JAVA, uses JAVAFX 1.8 and SQLlite as DB. My problem is, that if I create a Jar-File with Eclipse export (Runnable Jar -> Extract required libs into generated Jar - Finish) my program starts via jar. But I just can't get Maven to do the same jar from my project.

If I run my Maven build and launch the Jar it always says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC".  I tried already so many things with my .pom and assembly, but was not able to find a solution yet...

Does someone maybe has ideas how I can force maven to generate the needed project structure?

Heres a screenshot of the root of the jar. Left eclipse, right maven:

[image: Jar root screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just post your pom.xml ? You're probably missing dependencies here and / or the structure of your maven project is incorrect.

Comment: Please provide your Maven pom.xml file. Also, please provide the command you used to build your jar.

Comment: everything is in the pom.xml file...

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. It solved my problem partially, but I decided to start a new question because it's probably more a javafx problem than a maven problem.